# Suggestions for backing up php site and mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, backup

do you have any good suggestions how to backup remote php site and mysql, and upload it to another remote ftp? I do have shell access and it is linux system.

Kind of lame question when I post it like that, but I assume some script would have to be run on remote server with site, that would do this.

If you don't mind sharing your ideas, I would appreciate it.

Best,
Zeljko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the capabilities of your shell and the size of your site, but the first step could be very trivial: Use mysqldump and zip it together with your webpage. For uploading your archive you can maybe use [wput](http://freshmeat.net/projects/wput/) or simply fall back to [ftp](http://www.inlumineconsulting.com:8080/website/scripting.ftp.html) which should be available on most shells.

Comment: Seems like the way to go. I didn't know about wput which is probably what I need to simplify things. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) do dump the DB into a "data" directory within the site.
An alternative would be SELECT INTO OUTFILE if you already have the SQL scheme stored somewhere.

Use tar to pack up the website contents.

```
tar -xvf site.tar
```

Use FTP, SCP, SFTP, etc to transfer that to the new location, unpack, then depending on how the DB was dumped restore the DB and give it a whirl.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/examples.html)?

Take a look at the documentation and examples.

Otherwise, I think you should ask this on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: I wasn't aware of serverfault site :)

Answer (score 0):

I second rsync but with a helping of mysqldump to dump your databases to a plain text file (assuming the DB is not too large).