# Is there any script that can make full remote backup?

Tags: php, backup, database-backups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggestions for backing up php site and mysql db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056796/suggestions-for-backing-up-php-site-and-mysql-db)

Is there any php script that can do file system backup and database backup (preferably zip them together) and send the backup to a remote server?

Comment: A filesystem & database backup of what? A web-page? A full web-site? A whole server? Send them how? E-mail ? FTP? HTTP? Rsync? Please be more specific and tell us more about your environment. E.g. many virtual host providers have some sort of web tool that can get a backup of the hosted data.

Comment: Use cron with some bash script which backs up DB and FTP files and mix it together. `mysqldump`, `cp -R` and `zip`

Answer (score 3):

linux commands have better tools for this. you can access linux commands using the PHP exec() function. something like this:

```
// db
$db_backup_file = '/home/backup/db_'.date('Y-m-d').'.sql.gz';
$command = '/usr/bin/mysqldump -c -h'.DB_HOST.' -u'.DB_USER.' -p'.DB_PASS.' --default-character-set=latin1 -N '.DB_NAME.' | gzip > '.$db_backup_file;
exec($command);

// file structure
$file_structure_backup_file = '/home/backup/files_'.date('Y-m-d').'.tar.gz';
$command = 'tar -zcf '.$file_structure_backup_file.' /home/';
exec($command);
```

you will want to check the linux command options, then test and tweak in a safe environment. you can then ftp or email the files to wherever. or you could put the same stuff in a cron job.

Comment: you can not be serious with email?

Comment: heheh depends on your scale. i have used email to regularly send backups of a small database before.

Comment: well, my host doesn't allow exec...